# Bitbucket is not a constructor using bitbucketjs

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, dependency-management, bitbucket-api

Im using this [library](https://bitbucketjs.netlify.app/) to manage bitbucket api from nodejs.

I have received a message about a deprecated endpoint so I saw that library have released a new version (2).

So, I have uninstall bitbucket dependency and installed again to version 2.7.0

But now, Im getting an error like this:

```
let bitbucketAPI = new Bitbucket()
               ^

TypeError: Bitbucket is not a constructor
```

This is the change in package.json

```
-    "bitbucket": "^1.15.1",
+    "bitbucket": "^2.7.0",
```

And this is my code:

```
let Bitbucket = require('bitbucket')
let bitbucketAPI = new Bitbucket()
```

I have deleted package-lock.json, node_modules/bitbucket folder, update dependencies with npm update but anything works..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to load this module is this:

```
const { Bitbucket } = require('bitbucket');
```

This is shown in [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitbucket).

So, when you were just doing this:

```
let Bitbucket = require('bitbucket');
```

You were getting the module exports object, not the individual `Bitbucket` property of that object.  To further understand,

```
// get module exports object
const bitBucketModule = require('bitbucket');

// get Bitbucket property from the module exports object
const Bitbucket = bitBucketModule.Bitbucket;
```

And, the recommended method using object desctructuring:

```
const { Bitbucket } = require('bitbucket');
```

is just a shortcut way to do it with less code.

Answer (score 1):

[Linked](https://bitbucketjs.netlify.app) docs [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `Bitbucket`:

```
const { Bitbucket } = require('bitbucket')
```